# One SQL table for all or multiple tables per regression record?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I am moving a design flow consisting of running a regression consisting of multiple simulations run on a server farm from using files over NFS to using a MySQL DB for extra speed. (We have an associated flow that has just this optimisation so we know it can work).

We will probably run in the order of 1000 regressions over one year; each of approx 100K simulations, each simulation to store a mall record of its results/runtime/...

In the current flow, each regressions results are stored in a separate (CSV) file. Currently each regression in the DB is stored in the same table of regressions and all simulation results for simulations from every regression is all stored in the one sim_results table.

To minimise changes from the current flow, I would like to consider creating separate sim_results tables for each regression but

1. I don't know how to create a separate table from an iondividual regression record (which has ID as its primary index).
2. I don't know if I should do it this way - to better mimmick the current flow; orgo with the one sim_results table because it may be "The SQL way".

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the SQL way is typically that you don't create multiple tables which each correspond to a different series of rows, except in the case where you're breaking out those tables for the purpose of sharding the data among multiple nodes (e.g. horizontal sharding).  Horizontal sharding is generally a complex task that has lots of caveats.

But overall, the way you design your schema has to do with the use cases you need to suit.  Particularly if you want to run queries over many simulations at once, storing all the data in a single series of tables is how you'd do that.  If OTOH you don't really have any querying plans, then you probably don't need a relational DB in the first place.

I'm not sure of the format of your data, but one schema design that is common for large amounts of data to be "analyzed" is the [star schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema).    The wikipedia page is a good read.

If you are heading towards creating many tables, SQLAlchemy's `Table()` construct is a Python data structure, which you can build programmatically.  Build a function that creates new `Table()` objects as needed and then calls `create()` on them.    I've worked with companies that have had to work hard to get *off* of this particular design though so I'd really consider if this scheme is worth it.   Relational tables properly configured can store billions of rows without issue.

Comment: Thanks, the single table solution is what others have suggested too.